# How can I get an empty field when I click on the append using the useFieldArray of React-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hook-form

Whenever I click on the append button, the generated field value printed as a `[object object]` but I want to get a blank field.
I want to output like this : `"fieldName" : ["value1","value2"...n]`.
In this code, I get the output as I like, but every time I have to remove the `[object obejct]` that is printed in the appended field.
[image: Example Image:]

code link : https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-star-jif19c?file=/src/index.js:162-177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array contains only origin names and not objects of origin you should put `""` inside `append` function not `{}` object.

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    component="label"
    type="button"
    onClick={() => append('')}
>
    Add Items
</Button>
```